# Completing a probability statement

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, normal-distribution, economics

I have been asked to complete a probability statement assuming a *standard* normal distribution that $P(X≤1.5)$.

I just wanted guidance on what exactly I should be saying as I have not been given the mean or standard deviation to compute the probability.

How do you answer a question like this?

Comment: Because the support of any normal distribution is the whole real line, it would be correct (if not extremely informative) to say $P(X \le 1.5) > 0.$ However, unless you think this might have been intended as a 'trick question', look around to make _sure_ you are not given the mean and SD of $X$.

Comment: Does complete mean I am to comment on it?

Comment: In any math course, one should always feel free to question and comment. Thus my disdain of multiple-choice on-line courseware.

Comment: What does "complete a probability statement" mean? Are you translating from a different language? Does it say **standard** normal? Then you would know the mean and variance. Otherwise, it might mean it wants you to write the statement in plain language: "$P(X\leq 1.5)$ is the probability that the random variable $X$ is less than or equal to 1.5". (That interpretation is unlikely.)

Comment: Yes, sorry, assuming that it is a standard normal distribution.

Comment: Does that mean I assume it is N(0, 1)?

Comment: The tag (economics) seems out of place for this question.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, $X$ follows a **standard** normal distribution. This means that the mean is $0$ and the variance is $1$. This is often written as $$X\sim N(0, 1).$$

Since $X$ is already standard normal, then there is no need to standardize and you would use a table or calculator to find
$$P(X\leq 1.5) = \Phi(1.5)$$
where $\Phi$ is the standard normal cdf.

Comment: That has clarified a lot, I thought that was what z brought the mean and s.d. to.

Comment: Often, $Z$ is used to represent the standard normal. But any letter can be used, like $X$ in the example above. If instead $X\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, then $\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\sim Z$, where $Z$ is standard normal. I think that's what you're getting at.